# Render the depth buffer in OpenGL without shaders

Tags: c++, opengl, depth-buffer

I have the following C++ OpenGL code which renders the RGB values of pixels in a scene:

```
glClearColor(0.1f, 0.1f, 0.1f, 1.0f);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
glViewport(0, 0, _windowWidth, _windowHeight);

glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
glCullFace(GL_BACK);

glMatrixMode( GL_PROJECTION );
glLoadIdentity();

float aspectRatio = float(_windowWidth) / float(_windowHeight);
gluPerspective(60.0f, aspectRatio, 0.1f, 1000.0f);

glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
_camera.Update();
glLoadMatrixf(_camera.Matrix()[0]);

_scene.Render();

glutSwapBuffers();
```

However, I would like to instead render the depth buffer of the scene, i.e. so that each pixels value is the z-distance in front of the camera.

That is, I am currently getting the top image but I want the bottom image (image from [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Z_buffer.svg)):

[image]

How should I go about this? I don't think I'm using shaders (am I?) – and the advice given [here](http://www.gamedev.net/topic/621279-rendering-the-depth-buffer/) seems to suggest this might only be possible with shaders.

There is also [this code](http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/intermediate-tutorials/tutorial-14-render-to-texture/), although this too looks like it is using shaders. How difficult would it be to modify my code to use shaders?

Comment: I'm not a graphics expert but that ball seems a phong-blinn, probably also the monkey and the cube.. I believe you're using shaders but the main point is: how can we help without code?

Answer (score 6):

You can slurp the depthbuffer to host memory via `glReadPixels()` and `GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT` and re-upload the buffer as a `GL_LUMINANCE` texture:

[image: screenshot]

```
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>

#include <vector>
using namespace std;

void display()
{
    int w = glutGet( GLUT_WINDOW_WIDTH );
    int h = glutGet( GLUT_WINDOW_HEIGHT );

    glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT );

    glMatrixMode( GL_PROJECTION );
    glLoadIdentity();
    double ar = w / static_cast< double >( h );
    const float zNear = 0.1;
    const float zFar = 10.0;
    gluPerspective( 60, ar, zNear, zFar );

    glMatrixMode( GL_MODELVIEW );
    glLoadIdentity();
    glTranslatef( 0, 0, -4 );

    static float angle = 0;
    angle += 3;

    glPushMatrix();
    glRotatef( angle, 0.1, 0.5, 0.3 );
    glColor3ub( 255, 0, 0 );
    glutSolidTeapot( 1 );
    glPopMatrix();

    vector< GLfloat > depth( w * h, 0 );
    glReadPixels( 0, 0, w, h, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_FLOAT, &depth[0] ); 

    // linearize depth
    // http://www.geeks3d.com/20091216/geexlab-how-to-visualize-the-depth-buffer-in-glsl/
    for( size_t i = 0; i < depth.size(); ++i )
    {
        depth[i] = ( 2.0 * zNear ) / ( zFar + zNear - depth[i] * ( zFar - zNear ) );
    }

    static GLuint tex = 0;
    if( tex > 0 )
        glDeleteTextures( 1, &tex );
    glGenTextures(1, &tex);
    glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex);
    glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE );
    glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE );
    glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR );
    glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR );
    glTexImage2D( GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_LUMINANCE, w, h, 0, GL_LUMINANCE, GL_FLOAT, &depth[0] );

    glMatrixMode( GL_PROJECTION );
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho( 0, w, 0, h, -1, 1 );

    glMatrixMode( GL_MODELVIEW );
    glLoadIdentity();

    glEnable( GL_TEXTURE_2D );
    glColor3ub( 255, 255, 255 );
    glScalef( 0.3, 0.3, 1 );
    glBegin( GL_QUADS );
    glTexCoord2i( 0, 0 );
    glVertex2i( 0, 0 );
    glTexCoord2i( 1, 0 );
    glVertex2i( w, 0 );
    glTexCoord2i( 1, 1 );
    glVertex2i( w, h);
    glTexCoord2i( 0, 1 );
    glVertex2i( 0, h );
    glEnd();
    glDisable( GL_TEXTURE_2D );

    glutSwapBuffers();
}

void timer( int value )
{
    glutPostRedisplay();
    glutTimerFunc( 16, timer, 0 );
}

int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
    glutInit( &argc, argv );
    glutInitDisplayMode( GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_DOUBLE );
    glutInitWindowSize( 600, 600 );
    glutCreateWindow( "GLUT" );
    glewInit();
    glutDisplayFunc( display );
    glutTimerFunc( 0, timer, 0 );
    glEnable( GL_DEPTH_TEST );
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

Round-tripping to the CPU isn't terribly fast (especially with the host-side linearization).  You can use [PBOs](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_pbo.html) to make it a GPU-to-GPU transfer but you'll lose the linearization.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [Framebuffer Object (fbo)](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Framebuffer_Object) to render the depth values into texture. Then in a second rendering pass draw a quad over the whole viewport and apply depth texture on it.

Or you can write a fragment shader that will output fragments colors according to their depth, this can render in single pass.

See [here](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_fbo.html) some examples. You can find more searching for 'fbo'.